Reverse ForeignKey orm django
hi i am new to django orm , can some body help me
i have data models in django .
class userprofile(models.model):
       foreignkey User related_name='fU'
class A(models.model) 
      foreignkey userprofile related_name='fa'
Class B(models.model):
      forign key A related_name="fb"
class C (models.model):
      foreignkey B related_name="fC"
   

so what i am trying to achieve is , with User id i want to get information from all tables from  top to bottom hierarchy .All values from all tables .

So C records, or B, and A as well?

"i have data tables something like that" even if you give us code for only part of your models please ensure that it is valid code. What you've shared currently is simply not valid.

all recorde userprofile ,A,B and c as well

You can get the related C models wth:
C.objects.filter(Bfk__Afk__userprofilefk_id=my_id)
so the related_name=… [Django-doc] is not relevant here, but the name of the ForeignKey itself.
You can use a similar query for B and A.
